# Draw a marker on a gridview item

Tags: android, gridview, shapes

I would like to draw a triangle on the upper right corner of a `gridview item` as a marker. I can do this with a background image but would like to use `shape` drawing with `xml` because this way things look more georgeous :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:toDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="-40%"
                android:pivotY="87%" >
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                    <solid
                        android:color="@color/your_color_here" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: But Digital AlChemist answered first although his answer is not all correct about what I'd like to achieve. :D OK I change the answer back to you.:D

Answer (score 0):

There are already numerous resources available on the internet , However, the first link mentioned was helpful to me. However u can check below ones!

This [link](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/three-variations-of-image-squares/) might help u out in achieving the goal.

Using [Android Specification](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html) to draw triangle.

or drawing Triangle Using Canvas

Drawing [Triangle Using Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544668/how-to-draw-filled-triangle-on-android-canvas)

Comment: The page's panel say "More is not always better". I agree but "more $$ is always better :D" Thank you. your answer is accepted