# how to create a triangle shaped bitmap image ,to use it as marker icon

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

i tried using

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.default_marker);
    Bitmap bmp = b.copy(b.getConfig(),true);
    int w = bmp.getWidth();
    int h = bmp.getHeight();
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
              int c = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
                ColorDrawable d = new ColorDrawable(c);
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(d.getAlpha(), Color.red(sColor),Color.green(sColor),Color.blue(sColor)));
                }
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, false);
}
```

Here sColor is the color name;
it is creating **circle** bitmap, But i want to create triangle.

Comment: Have a look http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/10/android-custom-shape-imageview-rounded.html

Comment: Check this answer first it is easiest one answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22690364/5476209